# Can I change where RStudio saves snippets?

Tags: r, rstudio, code-snippets

I would like to change where RStudio saves the `r.snippets` file that stores my code snippets. According to [this site](https://support.rstudio.com/hc/en-us/articles/204463668-Code-Snippets), RStudio should save to `~/.R/snippets/r.snippets`. I use `R_USER=C:/Users/JT/R` in my `Renviron.site` file to set the location of `~`. I think this code works, because when I check the location of `~` in RStudio I get:

```
> path.expand("~")
[1] "C:/Users/JT/R"
```

However, when I edit the snippets in RStudio it creates the `r.snippets` file in the folder `C:\Users\JT\Documents\.R\snippets\`. I want the `r.snippets` file to be saved in the folder `C:\Users\JT\R\.R\snippets\`.

Any ideas what I'm doing wrong? Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Over on the RStudio Community site this same question was asked as [Can you change the directory the Rstudio looks for the r.snippets file?](https://community.rstudio.com/t/can-you-change-the-directory-the-rstudio-looks-for-the-r-snippets-file/18218)

Very helpful answer by RStudio employee kevinushey was:

> While that directory isn't currently configurable, you might have luck
>   creating a symbolic link (or, on Windows, a junction point) to
>   re-route the snippets directory to another location.

tom_greenwood, the user who asked the question followed up with details of the [steps he used](https://community.rstudio.com/t/can-you-change-the-directory-the-rstudio-looks-for-the-r-snippets-file/18218/3):

> ```
> 1. Put you existing r.snippets file in the new directory on the shared drive. I called mine 'snippet files'
> 2. Delete the snippets directory which is inside the .R directory
> 3. Run cdm as an administrator.
> 4. Enter the command mklink /D "C:\Users\name.surname\Documents\.R\snippets" "T:\shared directory\snippet files"
> 5. Restart Rstudio.
> ```